# How to add items from a listbox to another listbox?

Tags: vb.net

I know from textbox to listbox you can use something like:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text)
```

But how would this work between two listboxes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `SelectionMode` is set to `One`, and you want to **Copy** the selected item:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to **Move** the selected item, then:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```